# Insert array items line by line after an exact match in a file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have an array of strings in the Bash.
I want to search for a pattern in a file(ex: [##Test##]) and insert all of this array items line by line after this match.

How can I achieve this?

Sample Input File:

```
This the Title of file
//empty line

Some text here
====================
[##Test##]
- test1
- test2
====================
some other text here
```

Sample array:

```
("- test3", "- test4", "", "- test5", "", "- test6")
```

Pattern to find in the file and insert the array after that:

```
[##Test##]
```

Sample output file:

```
This the Title of file
//empty line

Some text here
====================
[##Test##]
- test3
- test4

- test5

- test6
- test1
- test2
====================
some other text here
```

I tried doing this with `sed`, But I only know how to insert a single line after the match, not the entire array.

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output and your attempted code.

Comment: Thanks but do add your attempt even if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Print your array into its own file and insert that from `sed` using the `r` (= read) command:

```
printf %s\\n "${yourArray[@]}" > arrayFile
sed '/\[##Test##\]/rarrayFile' yourFile
```

Or without the temporary `arrayFile` if your system supports process substitution:

```
sed '/\[##Test##\]/r'<(printf %s\\n "${yourArray[@]}") yourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try `awk` instead of `sed`:

```sh
# don't use commas between elements
arr=("- test3" "- test4" "" "- test5" "" "- test6")

awk -v ins="$(printf '%s;;' "${arr[@]}")" '1; /^\[##Test##]/ {gsub(/;;/, "\n", ins); print ins}' file

This the Title of file
//empty line

Some text here
====================
[##Test##]
- test3
- test4

- test5

- test6
- test1
- test2
====================
some other text here
```

Comment: It gives an error:
`awk: newline in string`
I think it is because that `\n` in the print.
I have tested this on macOS 10.15, Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you not using gnu awk?

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is acceptable since `ed` is available on a mac.

```
array=("- test3" "- test4" "" "- test5" "" "- test6")
printf '%s\n' '/\[##Test##\]/a' "${array[@]}" . ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed.